# Entity Framework Code First - is it possible to get EF to automatically initialise collections of child entities?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Suppose I have these in my model:

```
public class Foo {
 public virtual Guid Id {get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class Bar {
 public virtual Guid Id {get; set; }
 public virtual Guid FooId {get; set; }
 public virtual Foo Foo {get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to get EF to automatically create the Foo.Bars collection when creating a new Foo and adding a Bar?

```
var foo = dbContext.Foos.Create();
foo.Bars.Add(new Bar());
```

I do understand that I can initialise the collection myself (either in Foo's constructor or when I am creating it, but I wonder if there is any way to get EF to do it.

Comment: I can tell you when I used EF4.1 database first it just did the equivalent of Bars = new HashSet<Bar>(); in the constructor for Foo, so I'm suspecting you have to do it yourself in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Framework does not provide anything out of the box for this. You would have to write your own method for this.

```
public class FooService
{
    ......

    Public Foo Create()
    {
        var foo = dbContext.Foos.Create();
        foo.Bars.Add(new Bar());

        return foo;
    }

    .......
}
```

Comment: In your code, aren't you using foo.Bars without assigning it to a , this resulting in a null reference exception?